# Why there is no ".exe" in task manager processes

Tags: process, exe, file-extension, taskmanager

As I looked into task manager I noticed that every application like Google, Spotify, Discord or Steam doesn't have ".exe" extension at the end of it's name. Interestingly if I create my own app in c++
and run it. It does have ".exe" at the end of it's name. Im just a little curious is it possible to remove ".exe" from program so it doesn't dispaly with it in task manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `File description` in your version resource.

If you don't, Task Manager shows you the filename.